# Code giving blank output working on only particular Website while both websites are exactly same

Tags: python, web-scraping

I scraping a district school website in which all website build are same every URL in websites are completely same except their names. The code I use only working on one school when I put it other school name it giving blank output anyone help me where I am going wrong. Here is the working code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff-directory? 
field_last_name_from=&field_last_name_to=&items_per_page=10&keywords=&page={page}'
data = []
for page in range(0,2):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page)).text,'lxml')
    try:
        for u in ['https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu'+link.a.get('href') for link in 
        soup.table.select('tr td[class="views-field views-field-rendered-item"]')]:
      
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).text,'lxml')
            d={
                'Name': soup2.select_one('h1.node__title.fcps-color--dark11').get_text(strip=True), 
                'Position': soup2.select_one('h1+div').get_text(strip=True),
                'contact_url': u
                }
            data.append(d)
    except:
        pass

df=pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('fcps_school.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

here is the other URL I am trying to scrap:

```
https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff-directory?keywords=&field_last_name_from=&field_last_name_to=&items_per_page=10&page=
https://aldrines.fcps.edu
```

Comment: try and print the response you get before you try and manipulate it into your shape ... and the status code for it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've scraped 10 pages as an example without changing anything from the existing code and it's working fine and also getting the same output in csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff-directory?field_last_name_from=&field_last_name_to=&items_per_page=10&keywords=&page={page}'
data = []
for page in range(0,10):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page)).text,'lxml')
    try:
        for u in ['https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu'+link.a.get('href') for link in 
        soup.table.select('tr td[class="views-field views-field-rendered-item"]')]:
      
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).text,'lxml')
            d={
                'Name': soup2.select_one('h1.node__title.fcps-color--dark11').get_text(strip=True), 
                'Position': soup2.select_one('h1+div').get_text(strip=True),
                'contact_url': u
                }
            data.append(d)
    except:
        pass

df=pd.DataFrame(data)#.to_csv('fcps_school.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         Name                              Position                                        contact_url
0       Bouchera Abutaa               Instructional Assistant   https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/bouchera-abutaa    
1      Margaret Aderton     Substitute Teacher - Regular Term  https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/margaret-aderton    
2        Aja Adu-Gyamfi                  School Counselor, HS    https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/aja-adu-gyamfi    
3          Paul Agyeman                          Custodian II      https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/paul-agyeman    
4               Jin Ahn                  Food Services Worker           https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/jin-ahn    
..                  ...                                   ...                                                ...    
95      Tiffany Haddock                  School Counselor, HS   https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/tiffany-haddock    
96        Heather Hakes  Learning Disabilities Teacher, MS/HS     https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/heather-hakes    
97       Gabrielle Hall  History & Social Studies Teacher, HS    https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/gabrielle-hall    
98       Sydney Hamrick                   English Teacher, HS    https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/sydney-hamrick    
99  Anne-Marie Hanapole                   Biology Teacher, HS  https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu/staff/anne-marie-ha...    

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

**Update:**
Actually, success of webscraping not noly depends on good coding skill but also 50% success depends on good understanding the website.

Domain name:

1. `https://fairfaxhs.fcps.edu`

and

2.`https://aldrines.fcps.edu`

aren't the same and h1 tag's  attribute value is a bit difference, otherwise, the both website's structure is alike.

**Working code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff-directory?field_last_name_from=&field_last_name_to=&items_per_page=10&keywords=&page={page}'
data = []
for page in range(0,10):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page)).text,'lxml')
    try:
        for u in ['https://aldrines.fcps.edu'+link.a.get('href') for link in soup.table.select('tr td[class="views-field views-field-rendered-item"]')]:
      
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).text,'lxml')
            d={
                'Name': soup2.select_one('h1.node__title.fcps-color--dark7').get_text(strip=True), 
                'Position': soup2.select_one('h1+div').get_text(strip=True),
                'contact_url': u
                }
            data.append(d)
    except:
        pass

df=pd.DataFrame(data)#.to_csv('fcps_school.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Name  ...                                        contact_url
0   Jamileh Abu-Ghannam  ...  https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/jamileh-abu-gh...
1          Linda Adgate  ...       https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/linda-adgate
2           Rehab Ahmed  ...        https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/rehab-ahmed
3      Richard Amernick  ...   https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/richard-amernick
4             Laura Arm  ...          https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/laura-arm
..                  ...  ...                                                ...
95     Melissa Weinhaus  ...   https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/melissa-weinhaus
96      Kathryn Wheeler  ...    https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/kathryn-wheeler
97        Latoya Wilson  ...      https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/latoya-wilson
98          Shane Wolfe  ...        https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/shane-wolfe
99     Michael Woodring  ...   https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff/michael-woodring

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: The code is working perfectly with the website you use but not working with other website both website are similar try this URL : https://aldrines.fcps.edu/staff-directory?keywords=&field_last_name_from=&field_last_name_to=&items_per_page=10&page=

Comment: @Syed, see the updated ResultSet